# HTTPS on iPhone - What kind of encryption?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, encryption, app-store

I'm using an `NSMutableURLRequest` in an iPhone app, that uses a `Content-Type`:

```
application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

The protocol is `https`.

From what I understand, this means the app uses encryption. But, what *kind* of encryption? According to Apple's export compliance page, they need to know whether I use > 64-bit symmetric or > 1024-bit asymmetric algorithms.

I honestly have no idea whether I do or not! Is there any simple answer to this question?

Comment: The content type is irrelevant - that's standard for a no-file-uploads form post. It's only the protocol that matters. The actual encryption will be negotiated between your device and the remote server. I suspect that given you're just using built-in Apple APIs your app doesn't count as using encryption.

Comment: Using built-in Apple APIs requires export compliance: "If I use the encryption available in the iOS or Mac OS X, do I still need to obtain U.S. government approval? What should I do about the source code, since I can’t provide it to them? 
You still need to submit your app to the U.S. Bureau of Industry and Security (BIS) for approval because they want to know how you are using encryption in your particular app, even though they have already approved the encryption in the iOS and Mac OS X."

Comment: I would recommend researching further as you are not using encryption in your software, per se, you are connecting to servers using built-in applications for which approval has already been granted.  IANAL, but that's the tack I would take.

Comment: Are you using it for something other than authentication? If you are only using it for authentication and are using the standard library you are not going to have to worry about a CCATs request based on what I've seen.

Comment: I'm using the Dropbox API, which appears to also transmit file data over HTTPS using these NSURLRequest objects. (In addition to transmitting the username/password information.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the NSMutableURLRequest uses the standard root certificates stored on the phone, you may not have to worry about it at all.

Also the form encoding is not part of the connection security, it's just about how fields are passed to the server in the request.  It's independent of HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any reason you should care about this, the api should handle everything for you. However to answer you question the bit depth of the encryption is based on the certificate the site uses, so it can change for each site.  Also you must have an ssl certificate installed on your site to use encryption you can't just use https as the protocol and hope it will work :)